# Select where date relative to now()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find all results with an end date within 30 days of now. The query I am trying for is:

```
SELECT * FROM title WHERE sales_end-date < now() + 30 days
```

How would I do this properly?

Comment: How could it now() +, it should be now() -

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `INTERVAL`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM title 
 WHERE sales_end-date < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Comment: There is also a `DATE_SUB()` function.

Answer (score 1):

To give the exact answer to your question, using the fuction now, the ONLY thing you were missing is the word INTERVAL! (And remove s from day(s))

```
SELECT * 
FROM title 
WHERE sales_end-date < now() + INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

Comment: You can change, +/- DAY/HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND/YEAR.

Answer (score 1):

for those using SQL on SnowFlake, the key part would be:

```
WHERE sales_end-date < dateadd('day', 30, current_timestamp())
```

Comment: Snowflake now supports also `+ 30` as well as `+ INTERVAL '30 days'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM title WHERE sales_end-date < (TO_DAYS(NOW() +30))
```